# No access to 3rd and 4th levels on Macbook with Danish KB layout

Tags: keyboard-layout, macbook, settings

My Danish keyboard layout is not supported in Ubuntu, here's the layout

[image]

Available danish layouts on Ubuntu exclude the traditional mac function key. As a result I cant get to the 3rd and 4th levels of any key some are generally useful like the '@' symbol

Answer (score 0):

You need to set this up yourself. Go to [ System -> Preferences -> Keyboard ].

Under [ Layouts ], make sure that Danish/Denmark Macintosh is the selected one, and select Apple Macbook under [ Keyboard Model ]. Then click [ Options... ]. The list presented to you should contain an entry regarding what button(s) to use as 3rd level modifier keys.

Generally, many applications will expect the alt key to function as an alt key, so I would recommend not using that as a modifier in Ubuntu.